# Show Text on Image by default

Tags: html, css

I am using this [HTML](http://designhooks.com/freebies/nava-clean-responsive-html-template/) template, see same in action [here](http://designhooks.com/html-demo/nava/)

Once you Scrolldown then you will see "EXPLORE OUR TOP DESTINATIONS" section, And as you can see on hover, I am getting City and Country name...

But What If I want to show, City and Country name by default, like still we are showing on hover only.

```css
/* -------- Destinations -------- */

.destination-box {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.destination-box .box-cover {
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 0;
}
.destination-box img {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.045);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.045);
  transform: scale(1.045);
  width: 100%;
}
.destination-box .boats-qty {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #e7434e;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}
.destination-box .boats-qty::before {
  content: "";
  font-family: icomoon;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.destination-box .box-details {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}
.destination-box .box-details::before {
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: -15px;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #000);
}
.destination-box .box-meta {
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.destination-box .box-meta .city,
.destination-box .box-meta .country {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
}
.destination-box .box-meta .city {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 7.5px;
}
.destination-box .box-meta .country {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.destination-box:hover .box-details::before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.destination-box:hover .box-meta {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.destination-box:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
/* --- Loading Destinations Box --- */

.load-destinations-box {
  display: none;
}
.load-destinations-box .destination-box {
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.load-destinations-box.open .destination-box {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
  <div class="destination-box">
    <div class="box-cover">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/destination-3.jpg" alt="destination image" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="box-details">
      <div class="box-meta">
        <h4 class="city">Ibiza</h4>
        <p class="country">Spain</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace below classes in screen.css

```
.destination-box .box-details::before {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: -15px;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #000);
}

.destination-box .box-meta {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `visibility: hidden` and `opacity: 0` from the `.destination-box .box-meta` style as follows:

```
.destination-box .box-meta{
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

This will make the `div` containing the information vissible.

The `transition` and `transform` styling can also removed if you wish, seeing as it will no longer be used by the `hover` effect.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the hover and made full css file for you.

you can find the changes.

replace css with below code

```
.destination-box {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.destination-box .box-cover {
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 0;
}
.destination-box img {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.045);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.045);
  transform: scale(1.045);
  width: 100%;
}
.destination-box .boats-qty {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #e7434e;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}
.destination-box .boats-qty::before {
  content: "";
  font-family: icomoon;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.destination-box .box-details {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}
.destination-box .box-details::before {
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: -15px;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #000);
}
.destination-box .box-meta {
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 50%);
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.destination-box .box-meta .city,
.destination-box .box-meta .country {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
}
.destination-box .box-meta .city {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 7.5px;
}
.destination-box .box-meta .country {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*changed the hover */

.destination-box .box-details::before {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.destination-box .box-meta {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.destination-box img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

/* --- Loading Destinations Box --- */
.load-destinations-box {
  display: none;
}
.load-destinations-box .destination-box {
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.load-destinations-box.open .destination-box {
  opacity: 1;
}
```